# Is there a way to stream Unity3D camera view out as a real camera output?

Tags: unity-game-engine, video-streaming

I am thinking of streaming out a Unity3D camera view as it were a real camera (same output, streams and options). I would need to do the following:

- Encode the frames in either: MJPEG/ MXPEG/ MPEG-4/ H.264/ H.265/ H.264+/ H.265+.
- Send metadata: string input/output.

I have not seen anything about streaming out unity camera views, except 1 question ([Streaming camera view to website in unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210098/streaming-camera-view-to-website-in-unity)).

Would anyone know if this were possible? and if so what would the basic outline to follow be?

Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: FMETP STREAM should support this feature, with low latency Unity Game View Stream for Quest 2, HoloLens 2 to website..etc on their demo: https://youtu.be/ZEOzbVy0UYU

Answer (score 0):

I would probably start with keijiro's FFMPEG Out plugin, I have a strong feeling FFPMEG allows streaming the video via commandline, which is exactly what keijiro is doing in his plugin, should be relatively easy to modify it to stream instead of recording to disk https://github.com/keijiro/FFmpegOut

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip. I will check the source code a bit more in detail and see if it can be easily modified to comply with my constrains. I did not know about this plugin so it is a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it via ROS creating a publisher and publishing camera stream from the Unity to the ROS topic :)